# Optimal Strategy for job offer

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Recently, I came across this question in an interview :
A manager wants to hire employees. An employee accepts offer iff at least k of his friends accept the offer. To what set of emplyees with **minimum size** should he offer the job such that maximum number of employees will accept the offer.

How to solve such types of questions ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem starts in a deadlock. If at the beginning no one has accepted, then the manager is out of luck since whomever he offers will reject (zero friends have accepted).

Comment: Is `k` the same for all employees?

Comment: Yes, it is same for everyone.

Comment: I think the answer is **k+1** ignoring the deadlock problem. Every person will see `k` of their friends have an offer and will accept.

Comment: As stated, if `k != 0`, there is no solution. If `k == 0`, the problem is not determined: if it offers to `n` people, all will accept, for any value of `n`.

Comment: i would say employeR should consider the a clique of size k+1 of the graph in which employee are nodes and edges are friendship relation. This may not be possible (if such clique do not exist) so aim for a k-core, a _minimal_ k-core. I don't know my algos but it seems it is not so easy to get

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the employer is gonna hire `N employee` from a single friend circle (everyone is friends with everyone in the circle).

So, for each number,`i`, from 1 to n, there should be at least `i` people who accept the job when `i-1` of their friends accepted the offer. Otherwise, there will be a deadlock.

For example, let say, N is 5.

```
There should be at least 1 person accepting the job without any friend accepting it (k=0).
Similarly, 2 people with at most 1 friend accepting the job(k=1). 
3 people with at most 2 of their friends accepting the job (k=2).
```

etc.

Otherwise, no one will accept the job which is a deadlock as mentioned in comments.

If `k` is fixed, there is only one solution which is when `k==0` as `@norok2` mentioned.